# azure sql server Client disconnected during login

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I'm getting the below error from the Azure SQL server, can someone help me resolve this?

Error:

> Err 26078, Level 14, State 1, Server SQL Azure, Line 1, Message "Client disconnected during login"

Comment: I did some search and it says this can occur when their outages,but i could see SQLAZURE status as green.May be you need to raise a ticket with Azure team

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I failed to mention that the user who's getting this error is trying to log to Azure SQL server using AD authentication (Azure AD has been federated with the on premise AD). Could this have any impact? 
The user can log without any issue most of the time it’s just that occasionally the user gets this error. Wondering if there any explanation you could think of?

Comment: If it's an AD user, did you go through the setting on the database server and database to allow this user access? AD access to Windows Azure SQL Database (PaaS) just made it to GA, and is something I've yet to implement. Also, that error will happen from time to time (once every few days, so make sure your app is ready to handle it.)  If your user in question is the ONLY one getting it, and they get it EVERY time, check the AD settings for the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a ticket wit Azure SQL DB team to investigate this problem.
Thanks, 
Mirek Sztajno, Senior Program Manager SQL Server Security team